# shp2pgsql text converted to number

Tags: postgresql, postgis, dbf

I'm trying to convert a set of DBF tables to POSTGRESQL and I've found that shp2pgsql included in POSTGIS could do this work, but if I looking at dbf  with an external program I see:

```
myfield as text of width 417
```

then I execute:

```
shp2pgsql -n ./CAN.DBF public.can -I | psql -d DESTDB -W LATIN1
```

and after import I see the myfield as:

```
character varying (10), filled with some numbers
```

why text are lost?

Comment: shp2pgsql can import text fields correctly. If it does not work for you, probably your dbf is damaged or was generated in a not standard why. How was generated the dbf? Share it here (i.e.thorough dropbox), I will try to import it.

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't upload the file it store personal data, and can't generate another one with sample data... looking at it with other DBF viewer it seems that the field is of type: Memo Variable-length memo field. The size of each field is limited to 4 GB. "The memo data is actually stored in a separate file, called a memo file, to reduce table bloat. " could it be that shp2sql miss those external files?

Comment: probably shp2sql only import the reference to the external data...Try converting the Memo Variable field to a standard text field

Comment: it seems that in the DBF are stored some reference number, that are stored in a FPT file. Can you point me out how can I link those files?